# JComboBox java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap / is in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, classcastexception

Im trying to add a new entry in my DB, inside the form I have a JComboBox.

Im getting this error, my first thought was my JComboBox was entering Strings, but I realized that I am getting integers from **getCod_category**. A few minutes before I changed the name of the package, even though I have changed it to how it was before I can not solve it

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be 
cast to class crud.M.Categoria (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; 
crud.M.Categoria is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I fill in the list

```
  try{
        ResultSet datos = libroDAO.obtenerListaCategoria();
        ResultSet datos2 = libroDAO.obtenerListaEditorial();
            while(datos.next())
            {
                lstCategoriaLibro.addItem(datos.getInt(1));
            }
            while(datos2.next())
            {
                lstEditorialLibro.addItem(datos2.getInt(1));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
}
```

This part is when i add a new entry to my db.

```
feedback = libroDAO.adicionaLibro(Integer.valueOf(txtFieldsLibro[0].getText()), 
                                                    txtFieldsLibro[1].getText(),
                                                    Double.valueOf(txtFieldsLibro[2].getText()),
                                                    Integer.valueOf(txtFieldsLibro[3].getText()),
                                                    ((Categoria) lstCategoriaLibro.getSelectedItem()).getCod_categoria(),
                                                    ((Editorial) lstEditorialLibro.getSelectedItem()).getCod_editorial());
        informarUsuario(feedback);
```

a

```
public String adicionaLibro(int isbn,String nombre, double precio, int stock, int cCategoria, int cEditorial) {
    LibroDAO libroDAO = new LibroDAO();
    Libro libro = new Libro(isbn, nombre,precio,stock,cCategoria,cEditorial);
        
        
    libroDAO.adiciona(libro);   
    String feedBack = "AGREGADO";

    return feedBack;
}
```

my crud.model.Categoria

```
package crud.model;

public class Categoria {

private Integer cod_categoria;
private String nombre;


public Categoria(Integer cod_categoria, String nombre) {
    this.cod_categoria = cod_categoria;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public Integer getCod_categoria() {
    return cod_categoria;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre= nombre;
}

public void setCod_categoria(Integer cod_categoria) {
    this.cod_categoria= cod_categoria;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Categoria ID:%d Nombre: %s ", cod_categoria, nombre);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you're building and launching your project.